# Perl ORM with Moo

Tags: perl, orm, cpan, dbix-class, moo

I'd like to use Moo as the Object Oriented approach for my app (with a relational database). I had used [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~abraxxa/DBIx-Class-0.08209/lib/DBIx/Class.pm) & [Rose::DB::Object](http://search.cpan.org/~jsiracusa/Rose-DB-Object-0.804/lib/Rose/DB/Object.pm) in the past, but these distributions are not Moo (neither Moose) related. I am looking for an ORM (or similar) with a Moo integration, do you know if this exists, or anyone has related plans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working on something very similar actually - I wanted a Moo-based approach, too. Technically I'm writing it to learn more about Moo, wasn't meant for anything serious, but you might be able to build on it if you wished :-)

https://github.com/bradhaywood/DBIx-Moo

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what do you mean by **Moo integration**, but I just installed the last version of `DBIx::Class` and saw that `Moo` was installed as a dependency. So, in version 0.08209, `DBIx::Class` has `Moo` as a dependency

Comment: I mean define domain objects (subclassing Moo), and using it to do database operations (CRUD)

Comment: DBIx::Class is what you're after. It's big and heavy and the query syntax isn't great when it gets complex. Still one of the best ORMs I've used though.

Comment: DBIx::Class plays nicely with Moo.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [DBIx::Mint](http://search.cpan.org/~jfraire/DBIx-Mint-0.04/lib/DBIx/Mint.pm)
You will need to add a role to your Moo classes

```
with 'DBIx::Mint::Table';
```

And also write a schema file. This schema file should have all information on classes you're going to use (class-to-table mapping, relationship to other tables/classes). No need to write schema file for each Moo class.

Comment: Old question, but this looks like exactly what I was looking for myself. Thanks a ton for posting this.